# Is there a pre-existing json template for SharePoint Online that enables visualising a list of URLs as cards similar to the image I have included?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When using Microsoft Teams, as soon as you enter a URL it creates a card for it pulling in the website icon and some details. I'm trying to create a list of websites in SharePoint Online and would like to visualise them in this way and was wondering if there was an already created template that does this.

I've tried searching the web and PnP but to no avail so I was hoping that someone may be able to point me in the right direction if this has already been done and made publicly available.

[Example website card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6LUR.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check [generic-tile-format demo](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/generic-tile-format) or [Items in Tile Layout with images demo](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/tile-layout-example-with-image).

[List of avaliable demos](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples)

Comment: Thanks for the response Lee.

I'd looked into these and are great for layout but the part that I'm trying to replicate that I have a knowledge gap on is the automatic collection and presentation of the favicon based on the URL that is entered.